# Can a magus use metamagic arcana with spell scar

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

My magus character was previously captured and with his hands shackled he had little possibilities of casting a spell and escaping. To prevent this in the future, I was thinking about a way i could escape while being bound, or grappled even. 
I was thinking that a spell like [gaseous form](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gaseous-form)  would be suitable for escape, but this spell contains the S component, making casting while properly bound difficult/impossible. I sadly found no other third level or lower spells that did not use the S component that would allow me to escape the shackles. If I could use the [still magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo---magus-arcana/still-magic-su) arcana, my problem would be solved if I had the spell prepared. 
Since gaseous form is more of an utility spell, I don't want to keep it prepared at all time, but rather make a spell scar, so that to can't be taken away. 
Here is what I want to find out: can I use the still spell arcana on a spell scar, and if so do I use it when I scribe the scar, or at casting. Also will this do anything for the spell level?

From the item creation chapter:

> A material component is consumed when she begins writing, but a focus is not. (A focus used in scribing a scroll can be reused.)

Another part from the item creation states:

> The act of writing triggers the prepared spell, making it unavailable for casting until the character has rested and regained spells.

There are four possibilities here.

1. <s>I can use the still magic arcana the moment I use the spell scar. The gaseous form spell is scribed as a normally with no special adjustments.</s>
2. I can scribe the gaseous form spell adjusted with the still magic arcana, and not need to supply somatic components at the time when i cast the spell. The still spell arcana states that the spell level is not increased, so I'm left with a gaseous form spell scar with that does not require somatic components to use.
3. I can scribe the gaseous form spell with an increased spell level appropriate for the meta magic feat.
4. Its not possible to combine metamagic arcanas with spell scars, since there is no adjustment for level for the spells, making this feature overpowered.

I would think option 2 is realistic, but it might create a power imbalance.
option 3 would be more fair.

Any ideas? thoughts?

**EDIT**: option one is no longer relevant since spellcasters can't use a metamagic feat to alter a spell being cast from a scroll as ShadowKras stated

Comment: Related Question: [Can Metamagic be used in Item Creation? What are the limits?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69293/can-metamagic-be-used-in-item-creation-what-are-the-limits)

Comment: looking at that question, I think it's clear that metamagic feats can be used in item creation. The difference in using an arcana is that it can be used unprepared without increasing the spell level. So to what extend can it be used, if at all for the creation of spell scars.

Answer (score 3):

It’s ambiguous and you will have to ask your GM. Personally, I would allow it.

#### Argument for “Yes, you can do this, and it doesn’t change the spell level”

Spell scars are created like scrolls, and

> Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal.

Your still magic arcana allows you to use Still Spell, a metamagic feat, while casting a spell. To put spells in a magic item, you cast the spell into it. So nothing is saying you can’t use the still magic arcana to cast the spell you put into the spell scar, resulting in a stilled spell in the spell scar.

#### Argument for “No, you can’t do this; you need the *feat*”

> Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal.

The still magic arcana is an arcana, not a feat, and therefore does not apply here. It’s like a feat, but not enough like a feat.

The best argument for this is actually not arcana at all, but metamagic rods, which function similarly. While I’d be inclined to happily allow a magus to create items of spells metamagic’d by his arcana, I’d be much, much less happy to allow a wizard to create cheap swift-action wands or something by using a *metamagic rod of quicken spell*.

#### Argument for “No, you can’t do this; something something preparation”

> You can't normally apply metamagics to a scroll on the fly, the scroll's spell has to be prepared using the metamagic.

Since the still magic arcana applies Still Spell on the fly, rather than preparing the spell with the metamagic, it cannot be used here.

This particular argument is bad because this wording is horrible. As written, it would mean that spontaneous casters cannot put metamagic in magic items at all, and that’s just terrible. Instead, this looks like a very-poorly-edited line intended only to introduce the idea that you need to factor the metamagic into the item’s original construction, as would be described in greater detail later. But they said “the scroll’s spell” rather than just “the scroll” and they used “prepared” instead of something else, so you could argue that spontaneous spellcasters are just out of luck.

But you shouldn’t, because that’s awful and this line is awful and Paizo’s editing is awful and to play Pathfinder you have to accept that fact so that you can understand that sometimes, they say really dumb things they don’t mean.

#### One thing we can be sure of: the feat would work

If you took Still Spell as a metamagic feat, you are a prepared spellcaster so you could prepare the spell with the feat and then stick it into the spellscar. Then it would work, though you would be stuck with the spell level increase.

Comment: good points although it provides multiple answers

Comment: @martijn In this case, multiple answers is the only *correct* way to answer the question. The rules are not clear or specific enough to correctly pick exactly one as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

### You have to prepare the spell-scar using the Metamagic feat.

You can't normally apply metamagics to a scroll *on the fly*, the scroll's spell has to be prepared using the metamagic (or cast using a metamagic feat you know, for spontanous casters). That means you can scribe a scroll of [Fireball](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) (3rd) using [Silent Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/silent-spell-metamagic---final) (+1), but it will cost the same as writing a 4th level scroll (700 gp).

This rule can be seen on the chapter about [Metamagic Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats):

> A spellcaster can't use a metamagic feat to alter a spell being cast from a wand, scroll, or other device.

And again on [Scribe Scroll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Scrolls):

> The **creator must have prepared the spell to be scribed** (or must know the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard) and must provide any material component or focus the spell requires.

Since, for all purposes, a spell-scar says it can be used as a scroll, that also means you can apply metamagics when scribing the scar just like you can [while scribing a scroll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation).

> Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal.

When crafting a magic item, you must be able to cast the spell at least once per day, for every day spent on the creation process. Since the [Still Spell Magus Arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo---magus-arcana/still-magic-su) does allow that, but you are not preparing the spell with it, you are using the ability on a spell prepared without the metamagic effect applied to it. And thus, *you cannot use the arcana for to scribe scrolls*.

You can use the ability to enhance your own spells, but for magical item creation, it still *requires increasing the spell level* and thus the item's cost (or scar's cost, in your case), which the ability also does not provide.

There is a [thread on paizo's messageboards](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ttbt?Scrolls-with-Metamagic#1) explaining how metamagics can be applied on magic items, and the consensus of the community (based on developer's posts) that **you cannot apply metamagic-reducing effects on the process of magic item creation**. Although *there is no RAW* for this, it seems to be the developers's intent.

Comment: good answer! So option 3?

Comment: Why does it “seem to be unintended” for the still magic arcana to not increase spell level? It explicitly says “This does not increase [...] the level of the spell.” I can see arguments for it not working for item creation at all, or arguments for it working without changing the spell level, but I see no argument for an in-between case.  If your argument is, instead, that the rules would say that you can use it without changing the spell level *but you think that is overpowered and would make a houserule to limit it*, you should be more explicit about that. Without speculation about intent.

Comment: Im mainly going by this post: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ttbt?Scrolls-with-Metamagic#5

Comment: I understand this answer, but I still find the wording really unclear. You state a lot of things as facts, but then only later introduce the idea that the rules are lacking and you are in fact attempting to report consensus and not the rules. It leaves the answer unclear as to what is rule and what is consensus or speculated intent.

Answer (score 1):

### You would have to take Still Spell (Metamagic) and prepare the spell-scar using the Metamagic feat.

As ShadowKras indicated,

> You can't normally apply metamagics to a scroll on the fly, the scroll's spell has to be prepared using the metamagic. That means you can scribe a scroll of Fireball (3rd) using Silent Spell (+1), but it will cost the same as writing a 4th level scroll (700 gp).
>
> This rule can be seen on the chapter about Metamagic Spells
>
> "A spellcaster can't use a metamagic feat to alter a spell being cast from a wand, scroll, or other device."
>
> Since, for all purposes, a spell-scar says it can be used as a scroll, that also means you can apply metamagics when scribing the scar just like you can while scribing a scroll.
>
> "Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal."

**However!**

### Still Magic (Su) Magus Arcana is an *action* not a metamagic:

> The magus can cast one spell per day **as if it were modified** by the Still Spell feat.

Emphasis Mine

You cannot *prepare* spells with the Still Magic Arcana, therefore you cannot prepare spell scrolls with it either. And because you cannot apply Metamagic effects to scrolls, you cannot apply Magus Arcana to scrolls, ever.

Comment: so option 4? Writing a scroll causes the caster to expend the spell from his memory. If you are using meta magic, the spell should be memorized as such. So it would be a still spell that is cast, not a normal spell. If at that time the magus modifies the spell with the magus arcana, it would still be a still spell that is being scribed

Comment: Yeah im actually doubting my answer is correct exactly for that reason. Allowing to use the arcana to prepare a scroll might be a house rule.

Comment: For the same reason you cannot use rods to scribe a scroll.

Comment: The reason is not because it says *as if it were modified* though, but because you didn't actually prepare it.

Comment: so 'as if it where modified' is not the same as 'modified by'? I guess that makes sense, but you could go both ways on this

Comment: Where does it say that it is necessary for the spell to have been *prepared* with the metamagic? Certainly, I should think, bards and sorcerers would object, seeing as they can’t do that even with the feat. The quote says “Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal.” *Using* is definitely not the same as *preparing*. The real issue I see is that it specifies “metamagic *feats*” which still magic is not. But since it functions like one, personally I would see that as close enough for this.

Comment: Oh I see, “the scroll’s spell has to be prepared” Ugh my god that is some terrible, terrible wording.

Comment: @KRyan regardless, you need the metamagic to *use* it; Still Magic arcana isn't actually a metamagic you can use, its an (Su) that Magus can perform. It could be houseruled any of OP's suggestions, but RAW does not say you can perform Spell Completions with it or any other suggestion of actually having Still Spell (Metamagic)

Comment: And yes, I agree the wording could be less dynamic.

Comment: I said prepared because the topic is a prepared caster. But the community consensus is that you cannot apply level-reducing metamagic effects when creating magic items. So a quickened rod cannot be used when creating a quickened scroll, you need to have the feat and increase the scroll's level by 4.

Comment: @ShadowKras If you can demonstrate that consensus, that would be a worthy addition to the answer.

Comment: It's on the thread i linked at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Ifusaso Debatable. It’s a supernatural ability that lets you use a feat. You are then using the feat, and that counts as “using metamagic feats.” Arguably, that is. It’s definitely not clearly so, but it *could be*. The wording is ambiguous.

Comment: @ShadowKras You should draw greater attention to that and to its significance and conclusions.

Comment: @KRyan it's also a developer RAI that when something says *as if*/*as modified by*, for all purposes it counts as you had it or as the referenced ability. As i said earlier, this answer is correct, but the reason is not because of that wording, but because it reduces the metamagic spell level.

Answer (score 0):

If Still Magic (Su) Magus Arcana is not a metamagic, then you can apply it when you cast your spell scar.

If you're saying that only metamagic feats with no level reduction can be applied when creating a magic item, then I would argue that anything that is not a metamagic feat could be applied when using a magic item.